# css text align center and background color

Tags: css

hey guys was hoping you could help me out..

The task seems simple but I just cant figure it out...

i.e

```
<div style="text-align: center;background-color: rgb(150, 161, 255);  " id="clock">
        asd
</div>
```

I have a div with some text in it, and I want to center align that text and make the background such that it stays only behind the text.

doing display:inline makes the background stay only behind the text, but then the text is no longer center alligned.

tried all display properties of css but no luck diddnt work.

been googling for like 20 minutes now but I guess im not sure what to search for .

any help would be appreciated.thanks.

Comment: check to this http://tinkerbin.com/HpwFpof7

Comment: @SVS:same effect as display:inline, the background color stays behind the text only, but text is no longer center alligned

Comment: wrap it around a div like this http://jsfiddle.net/7BbCm/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at this:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <span>
        my text
    </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    background: red;
    text-align: center;
}

span {
    background: lime;
}
```

Live example: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NKrKD/)

Comment: Just a couple of seconds faster than me

Answer (score 1):

Why not add a span tag to the text inside the div and style it?

```
<div style="text-align: center; " id="clock">
    <span>asd<span>
</div>​
```

And the css

```
#clock span{
background-color: rgb(150, 161, 255);
}​
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rvubJ/)

Answer (score 0):

please check i hope this will help you i tried to make according to your requirement..

```
 <div style="text-align: center;background-color: rgb(150, 161, 255); display:table; margin:auto;  " id="clock">
            asd
    </div>
```

demo :- http://tinkerbin.com/L8AOfd5P